# Why do Flutter widgets like Text do not offer a copyWith()?

Tags: flutter, widget, instantiation

For creating a new and slightly modified instance of a class in dart we often have or can create a `copyWith` method. In Flutter this exists for example in things like `TextTheme` or `MediaQueryData`, but not in widgets like `Text` or `ElevatedButton`. So it seems this is a deliberate design choice. What are the reasons for this?

Comment: I would guess that in general, it's rare to want two Text widgets with mostly the same properties.

Comment: ... and if you did, you'd create a new widget of your own that took the different values from its constructor and 'composed' the underlying Text widget. See: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/inside-flutter#aggressive-composability